# why wont my simple Apache node sever images render?

Tags: node.js

Why wont my code behave like an appache server? It rlinks and prints the html correctly but the images don't load correctly. What am I missing?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.get('/:path', function(req, res) {
    var p = path.join(__dirname,"/" + req.params.path)
    res.sendFile(p);
});

app.get( '*', function(req, res) {
    var p = path.join(__dirname, "/index.html")
    res.sendFile(p);
});

app.listen('3000', function () {
    console.log('app listening on port 3000!');
})
```

Allso I just noticed when I load javascript I get the error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < //for each js file`

Comment: Are you getting an error at the image URL? Or is it showing a broken img? Can you add the callback to .sendFile and see if you are getting an error? http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

Comment: Just showing a broken image. Nothing in the console

Comment: try `res.sendFile(p,function(err){ if (err) console.log(err); })`

Comment: `res.sendFile(p, function(err){ if (err) console.log(err); });` doesn't result in an error unfortunately. No leads

Comment: haha I added the edit I made to your code to see you edited to be yours

Comment: ? I didn't edit the code - I edited the comment because I forgot a \` at the end

Comment: you should check your p and req.params values to make sure they are what you expect. What kind of images are you using?

Comment: `C:\working\index.html` Is what I expect. I have been using the same code to server angular code for a while. So I'm confused what I am missing.

Comment: I meant in the app.get('/:path') route which is what is serving your images, yes? What URL are you going to for the image and where is it relative to your app path?